# How to prevent a push notification to be shown in the app (ios,android)?

Tags: push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

We have developed a tool to schedule push notifications to a target app (ios,android).
We are exploring a capability to discard a notification if it's fired mistakenly.
As of now FCM do not have that capability to discard a notification at the app end,once it's fired. Is there any out of the box solution to achieve such behavior ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you've discovered, Notification messages are automatically displayed by the system when the app is not actively being used, and this behavior cannot be suppressed. See the documentation for [background messages](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive#backgrounded).

If you want your application code to be able to decide whether or not to display a notification, send a Data message instead. Messages with only a `Data` block are never automatically displayed by the system, so your code can do whatever it wants. Note that in this scenario, your code will be fully responsible for displaying the local notification on the device.

For more information, see:

- The Firebase Cloud Messaging documentation on [Message Types](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#notifications_and_data_messages).

Comment: But fcm do not keep track of open rate for Data notification. And if the device is in DOZE mode, it will block the data notification, whether regular notification arrive as expected.

Comment: That's correct. So if you want FCM to track open rate, you will have to implement all logic on whether to send-and-display the notification on the server. There is no way to have client-side logic in that flow.